# Permission Denied - error message with CarrierWave and S3 (Amazon)

Tags: carrierwave

Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - c:/Users/myname/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Sample App/First App/first_app/uploa
ds/tmp/20110319-2137-6540-1543/album-the-bootleg-series-vol-4-bob-dylan-live-1966-the-royal-albert-hall-concert.jpg):

I have Carrier Wave configured with Amazon S3. I have an object profile_image with a field avatar of type mount_uploader. 
I get the above error when i try and save the profile_image object. The file does show up in Amazon but i get the above error message

Rails 3.0.3, Ruby 1.9.2 on a Windows 7 machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue here. I believe it's because the tmp file isn't being closed properly, and Windows won't allow it to be deleted.

EDIT:

Looks like it's been fixed in Carrierwave version 0.5.3 (see [Changelog](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/blob/master/History.txt))

Comment: I am actually still getting this error with 0.5.8 .. is there any other possible cause? when i use `storage :fog` i get the error, when i use `storage :s3` it doesn't give me the error...

Comment: still a problem in 0.5.8 under rails 3.1. windows-specific?

Answer (score -1):

I'm still getting that error on Windows, even with CarrierWave 0.9.0. I work around it by not testing it in development, rather push it to Heroku and use file uploads on my site, see if anything breaks. It seems to be fine.

Since my Windows laptop is nearing the end of it's useful life (too slow), my next solution to this issue  will be to wipe this computer, install a lightweight version of Linux, and see if that not only fixes the issue in development, but also extends the useful life of my machine.